# Django + React axios POST cant access Json properties

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I created two abjects that need to be treated separated in the backend, and sent it to backend with:

```
const order = {
    order_id: 1,
    customer: {
        name: "Jonas Illver"
        age: 18
    }
}

const car = {
    model: 'XHL'
    brand: 'Toyota'
}

const postData = {
    order: order,
    car: car
}

const res = await axios.post("orders/shipping/create", JSON.stringify(postData));
console.log(res);
```

And here I return the response:  *views.py*

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def shipping_create_order(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return JsonResponse(request.POST)
```

Here's what the console.log prints:

```
res.data // {"order:"{"order_id": 1, "customer": {"name": "Jonas Illver", "age": 18}}, "car": **car object content**}
```

The problem is that if I try to access those data in my django view, I always got a 500 error
I tried accessing it via:

```
order = request.POST['order']
# and also
data = json.loads(request.POST)
order = data['order']
# also
order = request.POST.get('order')
```

None os the above approaches worked, the only one that doesn't occurs an 500 error is the last one, using the `POST.get`, but as soon as I add the `if not order: return HttpResponse("No order")` line, it always return "No order"

How can I access specific info from the request.POST? Am I doing something wrong with the axios request?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `request.data` to get the data passed in the body. Have a look at the [rest-framework docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data).
Or another way to get the data is using `json.loads(request.body)`. But using `request.data` is a bit shorter as it does the `json.loads` job for you.

Comment: It kinda works, but still negative if I try to access the properties via `data = request.data` `data['order']` Do I need to treat the data in some way?

Comment: can you share the output of `print(request.data)` output?

Comment: When I print `JsonResponse(request.data)` my front gives me an object `res.data = {order: order_content_as_object, car: car_content_as_object }`